# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int' not working?

Tags: python

```
def failure():
    print("Unfortunately there is no solution for your device.")
    case_n = file = open("File Numbers.txt", "r")
    case_number = case_n + 1
    file.close()
    file=open("Case " + str(case_number) + ".txt" , "w")
    file.close()
def solution():
    file = open(phone_folder)
    ans = file.read()
    file.close()
    print(ans)


import os.path
phone=input("What make is your phone?")
phone_folder = (phone + ".txt") 
if os.path.isfile(phone_folder):

    solution()
else:
    failure()

input()
```

> **I am wanting to create a text file with a different number each time. And that writes the name of the phone in it.**

Comment: phone_folder = (str(phone) + ".txt")   first convert phone to string and then use concatenate operation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Read the first number from inside the text file?

Comment: What are you expecting `case_n` to be equal to?